# Create JSON from 2 strings from Database (Latency and Formatting Issues)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have created a JSON file from JArray in MVC application from 2 coloumns of my Database. But there are 2 issues:
1. The format of the file. It has extra brackets for each object.

```
[
  [
    {
      "Code": "1",
      "Name": "ASSETS"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Code": "2",
      "Name": "LIABILITIES"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Code": "3",
      "Name": "CAPITAL"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Code": "4",
      "Name": "REVENUE"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want it as:

```
[
    {
      "Code": "1",
      "Name": "ASSETS"
    },
    {
      "Code": "2",
      "Name": "LIABILITIES"
    },
    {
      "Code": "3",
      "Name": "CAPITAL"
    },
    {
      "Code": "4",
      "Name": "REVENUE"
    }
]
```

2. I have loaded the values in JArray from Database and then add it in another JArray. I am using 2 for loops. 1 for making JArray for 5000 entries. And the second for returning the next valid primary key from Database. But the problem is that, it takes more than 15 minutes to process the loops and return the JSON file. Why is there so much latency? And how can I make it fast. Here is the code.
           int idd =0;
           JArray Array = new JArray();

   ```
       for (int b = 0; b<5000; b++)
       {
           idd = dbid(idd);
           IEnumerable<MST> accList = new List<MST>
           {
               new MST
               {
                   S1 = db.MSTs.Find(idd).S1,
                   S2 = db.MSTs.Find(idd).S2
               }
           };
           JArray Arrayone = new JArray(
               accList.Select(p => new JObject
                           {
                               { "Code", p.S1 },
                               { "Name", p.S2 },
                           })
               );
           Array.Add(Arrayone);
       }

       string jsonfile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Array,Formatting.Indented);
       string path = @"C:\Users\Awais\Desktop\accounts.json";
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsonfile);

       return View(v);
   }
   public int dbid(int id)
   {
       decimal i = db.MSTs.Max(a => a.N100);
       MST m = new MST();
       for (; id <= i; id++)
       {
           m = db.MSTs.Find(++id);
           if (m == null)
               continue;
           else
           {
               break; 
           }
       }
       return id;

   }
   ```

When I tried the first loop for 100 entries, it took about 60 seconds to return the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modeling your JSON with anonymous type, you could've done it like this:

```
var array = (from coa in db.MSTs
             select new { Code = coa.S2, Name = coa.S1 }).ToArray();

string jsonfile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array, Formatting.Indented);
string path = @"C:\Users\Awais\Desktop\accounts.json";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsonfile);
```

It took me 319 ms for 100 000 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    var o = new List<RootObject>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
       o.Add(new RootObject
       {
          Code = "foo",
          Name = "bar"
       });
    }
   var v = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
```

Took around 274 milliseconds for my list to `Serialize`.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all loops and instead try to solve it in query and making a single array.

```
var k = (from coa in db.MSTs
                       select new { S2 = coa.S2, S1 = coa.S1 }).ToList().
                       Select(x => new MST { S2 = x.S2, S1 = x.S1 }).ToList();

                JArray Arrayone = new JArray(
                    k.Select(p => new JObject
                                {
                                    { "Code", p.S1 },
                                    { "Name", p.S2 },
                                })
                    );

            string jsonfile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Arrayone,Formatting.Indented);
            string path = @"C:\Users\Awais\Desktop\accounts.json";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsonfile);
```

It solves both problems. i.e. Brackets formatting issue and latency. Now with this code it works in less than 5 seconds